# How to I write ModelBinder that access all fields by prefix?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, custom-model-binder

For example, I like my ModelBinder to transform all "field_???" values to my single custom object.
How I could do that?
ValueProvider.GetValue only allows me to access by exact name, and I can't enumerate all possible fields...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public IActionResult OnPost([Bind(Prefix = "field_")] Whatever model)
```

Read the article https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Ok, it will call my binder, but inside binder I still can't enumerate fields. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you need a custom model binder and reflection. Try to take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0